# Thinktecture Identityserver and Cordova app - Which flow should I use?

Tags: cordova, oauth, thinktecture-ident-server, ws-federation

We currently have identityserver v2 (and ws-fed for our websites), and now we would like to authenticate with a phonegap app. How could this be implemented? I understand ws-fed is not an option, so for oauth our options are (I might be wrong here):

- Resorce owner flow
- Implicit grant flow

I've looked at the resource owner flow [here](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/11/01/oauth2-in-thinktecture-identityserver-v2-resource-owner-password-flow/), but it looks quite complicated, and I could find much documentation for it (read: a simple example ready to clone :-) )

The Implict flow I found some example [here](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2012/11/oauth2-in-thinktecture-identityserver-v2-implicit-grant-flow-with-javascript.html), but it seems to require a redirect_uri, and I can't understand how that could be achived on an app.

I noticed that in my STS admin site, there was an option for OpenID Connect also, could that be used?

I would be happy if someone could point us in the right direction?

Thanks for any help

Larsi

*I've seen that in v3 some new possibilities are present (an maybe even a phonegap sample [here](https://github.com/ciaranj/OIDCPhoneGapSample)), but unfortunatly no upgrade to v3 is currently planned*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was correct using openId connect with Implicit flow

```
GET /authorize?
response_type=id_token%20token
&client_id=s6BhdRkqt3
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient.example.org%2Fcb
&scope=openid%20profile
&state=af0ifjsldkj
&nonce=n-0S6_WzA2Mj HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
```

A if the user successfully authenticates they will receive a response like the following

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://client.example.org/cb#
access_token=SlAV32hkKG
&token_type=bearer
&id_token=eyJ0 ... NiJ9.eyJ1c ... I6IjIifX0.DeWt4Qu ... ZXso
&expires_in=3600
&state=af0ifjsldkj
```

Many openID connect libraries just parse the response and extract the relevant values the redirect is ignored